# add a variable session in entity?

Tags: symfony, session, entity

i create an entity "Products".
in this entity, i get the price like

`public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }`

Indeed, i would like to add in this method a session variable for convert currency like this :

```
    public function getPrix()
{
    $devise = $this->session->get('CurencyToConvert');
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols='.$devise));
    $rates = $json->rates->CHF;

    return $this->prix * $rates;
}
```

but i think this is the wrong solution.
i don't know how to do to get an automatic conversion when i get the price!!

do I create a service for my checkout and a twig filter for my views?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Products class is a POPO (Playing Old PHP Object) it's really required to keep it simple which means this class must have only attributes like `price` and getters and setters for those attributes,

You can create a service to handle Currency conversion, and you can also inject it into a twig filter so you gonna have one piece of code implementing this functionality

Comment: ok this is what I thought.i did not know you could to inject a service in a twig filter!!thank you for the information!!

Comment: You welcome mate, and of course you can inject a service in a twig filter because a twig filter is wrapped in a twig extension which is a service so you inject another service into it easily, check this http://lrotherfield.com/blog/symfony2-tutorial-twig-extensions-and-dependency-injection/